# Does anyone know of a good alternative to Pipe Viewer for Windows Platform?

Tags: windows, scripting, windows-xp

If you do not know what Pipe Viewer is (I did not know about it until 5 minutes ago), then [this blog](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-pipe-viewer/) does a good job giving a brief introduction to it with some examples. I write a lot of Perl Scripts as an ETL developer and a lot of times, the files that I work with take really long time to operate with (unzipping, moving, etc). Therefore, this tool would be awesome except I work in a Windows Environment. If anyone knows of a tool that gives you Progress of an operation running in the pipeline, please let me know as that would make my scripts that much more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt such a tool exists for win32, but it should run on cygwin. But then again You probably don't use it :)

Comment: I know about Cygwin and I use Ubuntu at home so I would not come across such issues for my personal projects. However, since my company is a Windows Shop, its tough. I was fairly certain that such a tool may not be present in Windows environment but I thought It would not hurt to ask. Thanks tho!

Comment: needs elaboration how to get it going in cygwin

Answer (score 3):

I finally made it work on Cygwin environment though that is not answer for the original post.

`--disable-nls` does the trick.

```
./configure --disable-nls    
make    
make test    
cp pv /usr/bin
```

== by Kenji (k2) ==

Comment: Could you post this online somewhere so I can just get that pv.exe without having to setup a whole cygwin install? thanks

Comment: @davr  I just tried it, and it creates pv.exe http://ge.tt/1p2MrSG/v/0  but it won't run outside cygwin. outside cygwin  even with cygwin installed, it says cygwin1.dll was not found.   Inside cygwin it is fine. And for anybody trying to get the ./configure thing to work , download the tarball file http://pipeviewer.googlecode.com/files/pv-1.2.0.tar.gz  and follow the instructions in the answer here. ./configure is included in the tarball. What is in this answer automatically runs the c compiler so you'll need to choose C - gcc c in cygwin setup, and you need the make command as you'll see

Comment: @davr maybe you know a hack that lets you run it outside cygwin and without a whole cygwin install? do post if you do 'cos curious.

Answer (score 2):

[Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) has **pv (Pipe Viewer)** as [an available package](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fpv%2Fpv-1.4.12-1&grep=pv) since I don't know when... but it is **not installed** by default.

1. Download the Cygwin setup executablefrom the [install page](http://cygwin.com/install.html).
2. While installing cygwin, you need to **expressly search and mark** for installation **pv** found in the ***Utils*** section.

*If you have already installed cygwin, you can always add it later on by re-running the setup executable.*

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to use pipe viewer to catch the output performance (bytes/s) of a console application.

If you want to measure the performance IO read/write of a process, I recommend using *Process Explorer*. You can find performance for each process.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Answer (score 0):

There is a new utility I created named "[PipeViewer](https://github.com/cyberark/PipeViewer)" for Windows.
It's open source, it list all the current named pipes and show you all the details on each named pipe.

In the future we might add a monitor that check in real-time for new named pipes.